# Disable access to Mail Settings for users

Tags: g-suite

I use Google Apps for businesses and would like to disable access to Mail settings for a small subset of users. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this with Google Apps.  You *could* create your own version of Google Apps using their [API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_settings_overview) and perhaps lock some of those down that way.